# Hyperlinks in Cells using Python Tabulator

Tags: python, tabulator, quarto, tabulator-py

I am using Tabulator in Python to generate dynamic Quarto reports. I would like to embed a hyperlink in each cell to navigate to another page when clicked. I wasn't able to find how to do this from the documentation here: https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/Tabulator.html.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks largely to chatting with ChatGPT-4...

Need to use the `bokeh.models.HTMLTemplateFormatter` method:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HTMLTemplateFormatter
link_formatter = HTMLTemplateFormatter(template="""<a href="<%= value %>" target="_blank"><%= value %></a>""")
pn.widgets.Tabulator(pd_df, formatters={"col1": link_formatter})
```

Where pd_df is a Pandas data frame and "col1" is the column with the value for the hyperlink.